# use NGINX to proxy/tunnel to Docker Container

Tags: docker, nginx, port, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have Nginx running on my server (NOT dockerised) and a Docker container which needs to accessible via web (I believe it uses port 80). I have a subdomain (lets say its i.example.com) how do I connect this to the docker container? So that I can access this docker app via i.example.com

Answer (score 0):

With the information you've provided you are likely looking for a general idea on what you need to do. You need to associate the domain name with the ip of the server and then configure nginx to reverse proxy incoming requests to the container.

UPD:

Docker containers running

```
username@server:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
aba6e0180a14   mendhak/http-https-echo   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   127.0.0.1:8083->80/tcp   thirsty_hellman
2bc1fcdb1573   mendhak/http-https-echo   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   127.0.0.1:8082->80/tcp   silly_hellman
04f67b562f48   mendhak/http-https-echo   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 minutes ago   Up 13 minutes   127.0.0.1:8081->80/tcp   loving_poitras
```

basic local (non-dockerized) nginx server configuration:

```
user@server:~$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


    location / {
        root /var/www/example.com;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /srv1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_set_header X-SRV srv1;
    }

    location /srv2 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        proxy_set_header X-SRV srv2;
    }

    location /srv3 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8083;
        proxy_set_header X-SRV srv3;
    }
}
```

Checking output (same output in browser at http://a.b.c.d/srv3)

```
user@server:~$ curl localhost/srv3
{
  "path": "/srv3",
  "headers": {
    "x-srv": "srv3",
    "host": "localhost:8083",
    "connection": "close",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.64.0",
    "accept": "*/*"
  },
  "method": "GET",
  "body": "",
  "fresh": false,
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "ip": "::ffff:172.17.0.1",
  "ips": [],
  "protocol": "http",
  "query": {},
  "subdomains": [],
  "xhr": false,
  "os": {
    "hostname": "aba6e0180a14"
  },
  "connection": {}
}
```

Comment: My domain and IP are connected, i already have several sites running but i’m new to docker and all tutorials seem to insist on using a Nginx reverse proxy docker container but this conflicts with my host system Nginx. So I just need help configuring Nginx to reverse proxy requests to the container

Comment: Updated with config examples

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find this info anywhere, they were all saying to install Nginx via Docker. Now I just need to figure out what do with the ports since docker is using port 80 but so is my wordpress site 

Comment: if by 'docker is using port 80' you mean it is exposing port 80 and also maps it to a local port 80 - you have options - you can either have your local nginx do https, then you will be using port 443, or you can remap the container, so it doesn't "steal" local port 80

Comment: What does the `X-SRV` header indicate?